# How to fix "wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id " rowan atkinson" does not match any pages. Try another id!"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

My name is Tom! I am doing a Python3.9 project and when I run it, all the commands and functions work very well except the line 137 "wikipedia" when I say "wikipedia with the command" it will appear an error.
"wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id " rowan atkinson" does not match any pages. Try another id!"
I tried to fix it many different ways but the error still there. Hope anyone can help me to fix this error.

*Thank you very much!*

**Here is my code.**

```
#import
import datetime
import os
import pyautogui
import pyjokes
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import requests
import smtplib
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser as we
from email.message import EmailMessage
from datetime import date
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
import random
import os
import wikipedia
from subprocess import run
from typing import Text







user = "Tom" #your name
assistant= "Jarvis" # Iron man Fan

Jarvis_mouth = pyttsx3.init()
Jarvis_mouth.setProperty("rate", 170)
voices = Jarvis_mouth.getProperty("voices")

# For Mail voice AKA Jarvis
Jarvis_mouth.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)

def Jarvis_brain(audio):
    print("Jarvis: " + audio)
    Jarvis_mouth.say(audio)
    Jarvis_mouth.runAndWait()

#Jarvis speech 
#Jarvis_ear = listener
#Jarvis_brain = speak
#Jarvis_mouth = engine
#you = command

def inputCommand():
    # you = input() # For getting input from CLI
    Jarvis_ear = sr.Recognizer()
    you = ""
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as mic:
        print("Listening...")
        Jarvis_ear.pause_threshold = 1
        try:
            you = Jarvis_ear.recognize_google(Jarvis_ear.listen(mic, timeout=3), language="en-IN")
        except Exception as e:
            Jarvis_brain(" ")
        except:
            you = ""
        print("You: " + you)
    return you
print("Jarvis AI system is booting, please wait a moment")
Jarvis_brain("Start the system, your AI personal assistant Jarvis")

def greet():
    hour=datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        Jarvis_brain(f"Hello, Good Morning {user}")
        print("Hello,Good Morning")
    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        Jarvis_brain(f"Hello, Good Afternoon {user}")
        print("Hello, Good Afternoon")
    else:
        Jarvis_brain(f"Hello, Good Evening {user}")
        print("Hello,Good Evening")
greet()        


    

while True:
    # Getting input from the user
    you = inputCommand().lower()

    #General question.
    if ("hello" in you) or ("Hi" in you):
        Jarvis_brain(random.choice(["how may i help you, sir.","Hi,sir"]))

    elif ("time" in you):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        robot_brain = now.strftime("%H hour %M minutes %S seconds")
        Jarvis_brain(robot_brain)

    elif ("date" in you):
        today = date.today()
        robot_brain = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
        Jarvis_brain(robot_brain)

    elif ("joke" in you):
        Jarvis_brain(pyjokes.get_joke())

    elif "president of America" in you:
        Jarvis_brain("Donald Trump")

#open application
    elif ("play" in you):
        song = you.replace('play', '')
        Jarvis_brain('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    
    elif ("open youtube" in you):
        Jarvis_brain("opening YouTube")
        we.open('https://www.youtube.com/')    

    elif ("open google" in you):
        Jarvis_brain("opening google")
        we.open('https://www.google.com/')    

    elif ("open gmail" in you):
        Jarvis_brain("opening gmail")
        we.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/2/#inbox')    
    
    elif "vietnamese translate" in you:
        Jarvis_brain("opening Vietnamese Translate")
        we.open('https://translate.google.com/?hl=vi')    

    elif "english translate" in you:
        Jarvis_brain("opening English Translate")
        we.open('https://translate.google.com/?hl=vi&sl=en&tl=vi&op=translate') 

    elif ("open internet") in you:
        Jarvis_brain("opening internet")
        open = "C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\Brave.exe"
        os.startfile(open)

    elif ("wikipedia") in you:#can't use wikipedia
        you = you.replace("wikipedia", "")
        results = wikipedia.summary(you, sentences=2)
        Jarvis_brain(results)
        print(results)

#New&Covid-19
    elif ("news" in you): 
        newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key='5840b303fbf949c9985f0e1016fc1155')
        Jarvis_brain("What topic you need the news about")
        topic = inputCommand()
        data = newsapi.get_top_headlines(
            q=topic, language="en", page_size=5)
        newsData = data["articles"]
        for y in newsData:
            Jarvis_brain(y["description"])

    elif ("covid-19" in you):
        r = requests.get('https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/all').json()
        Jarvis_brain(f'Confirmed Cases: {r["cases"]} \nDeaths: {r["deaths"]} \nRecovered {r["recovered"]}')

 #can not use wikipedia!
    elif ("wikipedia") in you:
        you = you.replace("wikipedia", "")
        results = wikipedia.summary(you, sentences=2)
        Jarvis_brain(results)
        print(results)

    else:
        if "goodbye" in you:
            hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
            if (hour >= 21) and (hour < 5):
                Jarvis_brain(f"Good Night {user}! Have a nice Sleep")
            else:
                Jarvis_brain(f"Bye {user}")
            quit()
```

**I will paste my error here.**

```
Listening...
You: Wikipedia Rowan Atkinson
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PC\Desktop\assistant\abc.py", line 138, in <module>
    results = wikipedia.summary(you, sentences=2)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 231, in summary
    page_info = page(title, auto_suggest=auto_suggest, redirect=redirect)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 276, in page
    return WikipediaPage(title, redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 299, in __init__
    self.__load(redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 345, in __load
    raise PageError(self.title)
wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id "roman atkinson" does not match any pages. Try another id!
```

***Thanks for any help!***

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: Your speech was misrecognized: "roman atkinson", rather than "rowan".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in Python using wikipedia module: wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id "harry plotter" does not match any pages. Try another id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69886443/error-in-python-using-wikipedia-module-wikipedia-exceptions-pageerror-page-id)