# Error in Python using wikipedia module: wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id "harry plotter" does not match any pages. Try another id

Tags: python, wikipedia

newbie in Python here

when I run this simple code (to load Harry Potter page and simply print it)
it returns me Error with the wrong name I wanted to search (harry plotter)
can anyone tell me how to fix? thank you!

```
import wikipedia

page = wikipedia.page("Harry Potter")

print(page.summary)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Lidor\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\search_engine.py", line 7, in <module>
  page = wikipedia.page(search[0])
File "C:\Users\Lidor\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 276, in page
  return WikipediaPage(title, redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
File "C:\Users\Lidor\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 299, in __init__
  self.__load(redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
File "C:\Users\Lidor\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 345, in __load
  raise PageError(self.title)
  wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id "harry plotter" does not match any pages. Try 
    another id!
```

Comment: cf. `page = wikipedia.page("David Beckham")`.  Something is up with the first page....

Comment: can you tell what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be a strange result of `auto_suggest` being set by default.  If you do

```py
wikipedia.page("Harry Potter", auto_suggest=False)
```

It works fine.  Otherwise it autocompletes `potter` to `plotter`, hence the error.

Comment: It worked! can you tell me (for me to get experience) how you came to this solution? so in the future I can solve this kind of stuff myself

Comment: @LidorTubul I was mostly lucky: there were a couple of issues/PRs mentioning `auto_search` on the github page which I looked at before trying anything.  But if you look at [the logic here](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/blob/master/wikipedia/wikipedia.py#L268-L276) you can see that `title` is replaced in the `auto_search` case *before* any query is done (which is probably a design error, but I don't know the library).  I was looking for something like 'auto_search' or 'autocorrect' as it had replaced 'potter' with 'plotter' which was clearly some autocorrect bug. :)

Comment: @LidorTubul in general a decent approach is 1. follow any hunches for a few minutes or so (which worked in this case), 2. look at the issues on github to see if anyone else has reported it, 3. read the source.  I can't stress 3 enough (although I often do it last with a well maintained library).  If you want to know how code works, 'use the source, luke'.  Particularly given how wonderfully readable python is.  Plus, you will learn a lot by reading it (even if you get some rubbish library and you learn 'I don't want to use this library').